# jQuery: why does index() return -1 after dynamically changing DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

And some jQuery to add a class to one of the elements, then return that element's position in the list.

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
  $('li:nth-child(2)').addClass('selected'); // select the second item (this number varies in the actual code)
  index = $('li').index('.selected');
  alert('selected item is at index '+index);
});
```

I would think this should print out `'selected item is at index 1'`, but instead it prints out `'selected item is at index -1'`.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cvnok

Would anyone be able to shine some light on why this happens?

---

*Edit*

Weird observation: if you change `$('li:nth-child(2)')` to `$('li:nth-child(1)')`, then the function prints out `'selected item is at index 0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) will work in three cases.

> .index()
>       This signature does not accept any arguments.
>
> .index( selector )
>       A selector representing a jQuery collection in which to look for an element.
>
> .index( element )
>       The DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to look for.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
  $('li:nth-child(2)').addClass('selected'); // select the second item (this number varies in the actual code)
  index = $('li').index($('.selected')); // this will search for element with class selected.
  alert('selected item is at index '+index);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/us26J/)**

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Thanks, this works. Would you mind explaining why this example works with an object argument but not a string argument? [This summary from jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/understanding-index/) didn't help me understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks, it clicked for me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This For Find Selected Index. 


$(document).on('click',function(){


$('li:nth-child(2)').addClass('selected');
      $('li').each(function(index, element) {
       if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
       {
            alert('selected item is at index '+index);

       }
        });
    });
```